# Send a request to an Office add-in

Tags: javascript, http-post, ms-office, office-js, postmessage

I am making an Excel addin with [JavaScript API for Excel](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-javascript-programming-overview?product=excel). The entry of the addin is `addin.html`, and it calls JS, CSS files. All the files are hosted in `www.myexample.com`.

When we click on a button in the addin, it will popup a browser window by `window.open("https://www.myexample.com/post/", "popup")`. The page with `post.html` as template is built by `angularjs` and `ui-router`. The server and the client are also hosted in `www.myexample.com`.

The controller of `post.html` needs to send request from time to time to `addin.html`. For example, `post.html` sends an address `A1` to `addin.html`, and expects to receive the current value of Cell `A1`. It is easy for `addin.html` to get cell value from Excel **with some async functions** by JavaScript API for Excel. Whereas, my question is **how to implement the request (of getting cell value from an address) in the controller of `post.html`.**

If we use `$http.post`, is it possible to send a request to `addin.html`, which does not have a server?

```
var getValue = function (address) {
    return $http.post('...', { address: address })
        .then(function (res) {
             // maybe do something with res
             return res
        }
}
```

If we use `postMessage`, we could implement listeners in `post.html`, which are reactive. I can NOT imagine how to send actively a request and wait for a response.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we open the popup browser by `window.open` as described in the OP, we could send data between the popup and the add-in by `postMessage`.

If we open a dialog box suggested by @MohamedShakeel we could send data by `messageParent` and `localStorage`.

Both of the two ways work.

> I can NOT imagine how to send actively a request and wait for a
>   response.

We could wait for a response, eg, a message from the add-in, by manually making a promise like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42757371/702977). Thus, we will be able to define

```
var getValue = function (address) {
    return sendRequestByPostMessage()
        .then(function () {
             return waitForResponse()
                 .then(function (res) {
                     // treatTheResponse
                 })
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening a window when we click on a button in the addin, you could create a DispalyDialog and open it. From there you can send requests to the addin using `messageParent()` method. For handling the received message, you could do something like

```
Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, myHandler);

function myHandler(eventArgs) {
 //Do some processing
}
```

After the processing is done, you could store the result in `localStorage` so that it is available in the DisplayDialog.

This is not a clear way of accomplishing what you need but I am sure that it will get the task done. If you find out any other solutions, please do update here.

Comment: It is good to know [Dialog](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)... thank you...